# How to Fix <Select> to load dynamically on another <select> option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to write a code for DYNAMIC NIGERIAN STATES AND LGs.
On clicking on a select option it dynamically load another select option with declared values.

This is the html code

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.3-jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<select name="state" id="state">
  <option selected="selected">Select item...</option>
  <option value='Abia'>Abia</option>
  <option value='Adamawa'>Adamawa</option>
</select>
```

this is the second select option

```
<select name="lga" id="lga">
</select>
<script>
```

Jquery code

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function() {
  $("#state").change(function() {
    var state = $(this).val();
    var lga = eval(state);
  })
}); 
</script>
```

And the javascript declaration for the LGA

```
</script>    
var Abia = ['Select item...', 'Aba North', 'Aba South', 'Arochukwu', 'Bende', 'Ikwuano', 'Isiala Ngwa North', 'Isiala Ngwa South', 'Isuikwuato', 'Obi Ngwa', 'Ohafia', 'Osisioma', 'Ugwunagbo', 'Ukwa East', 'Ukwa West', 'Umuahia North', 'muahia South', 'Umu Nneochi'];

var Adamawa = ['Select item...', 'Demsa', 'Fufure', 'Ganye', 'Gayuk', 'Gombi', 'Grie', 'Hong', 'Jada', 'Larmurde', 'Madagali', 'Maiha', 'Mayo Belwa', 'Michika', 'Mubi North', 'Mubi South', 'Numan', 'Shelleng', 'Song', 'Toungo', 'Yola North', 'Yola South'];
</script>
```

I expect the on selecting any options from the state it loads dynamically in the lga select options.

[image]

Comment: `var lga = eval(state);`????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments inline and never, never, never use `eval()`:

```js
// Set up your options in an Object
let options = {
  Abia : ['Select item...', 'Aba North', 'Aba South', 'Arochukwu', 'Bende', 'Ikwuano', 'Isiala Ngwa North', 'Isiala Ngwa South', 'Isuikwuato', 'Obi Ngwa', 'Ohafia', 'Osisioma', 'Ugwunagbo', 'Ukwa East', 'Ukwa West', 'Umuahia North', 'muahia South', 'Umu Nneochi'],
  Adamawa : ['Select item...', 'Demsa', 'Fufure', 'Ganye', 'Gayuk', 'Gombi', 'Grie', 'Hong', 'Jada', 'Larmurde', 'Madagali', 'Maiha', 'Mayo Belwa', 'Michika', 'Mubi North', 'Mubi South', 'Numan', 'Shelleng', 'Song', 'Toungo', 'Yola North', 'Yola South']
};

// Don't use `window.onload` unless you need to wait for 
// external resources to finish loading. Instead, just pass
// the function you want executed when the DOM is ready 
// directly to JQuery
jQuery(function() {
  $("#state").change(function() {
    let output = ""; // will hold the HTML for second list
   
    // Loop over the array that matches the selected state
    options[$(this).val()].forEach(function(st){
      output += "<option>" + st + "</option>";
    });
    
    $("#lga").html(output); // Inject the HTML string into the list
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="state" id="state">
  <option selected="selected">Select item...</option>
  <option value='Abia'>Abia</option>
  <option value='Adamawa'>Adamawa</option>
</select>
<select name="lga" id="lga"></select>
```

Comment: This line of code is displaying error " let output = "";  "

Comment: @MrIbra Then you haven't set up the code as I've shown, because as you can see from the code here, there is no error.

Answer (score 0):

```js
   var Abia = ['Select item...', 'Aba North', 'Aba South', 'Arochukwu', 'Bende', 'Ikwuano', 'Isiala Ngwa North', 'Isiala Ngwa South', 'Isuikwuato', 'Obi Ngwa', 'Ohafia', 'Osisioma', 'Ugwunagbo', 'Ukwa East', 'Ukwa West', 'Umuahia North', 'muahia South', 'Umu Nneochi'];

    var Adamawa = ['Select item...', 'Demsa', 'Fufure', 'Ganye', 'Gayuk', 'Gombi', 'Grie', 'Hong', 'Jada', 'Larmurde', 'Madagali', 'Maiha', 'Mayo Belwa', 'Michika', 'Mubi North', 'Mubi South', 'Numan', 'Shelleng', 'Song', 'Toungo', 'Yola North', 'Yola South'];


    jQuery(window).on('load', function() {
      $("#state").change(function() {
        var state = $(this).val();
        var lga = eval(state);
        $("#lga").html("");
        lga.forEach(function(text){
          $("#lga").append(`<option value="${text}">${text}</option>`);
        });
      })
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select name="state" id="state">
      <option selected="selected">Select item...</option>
      <option value='Abia'>Abia</option>
      <option value='Adamawa'>Adamawa</option>
    </select>
    <select name="lga" id="lga">
    </select>
```

Comment: Good answers on Stack Overflow should be more than just working code. You should explain what you did and why you did it. Also, you should never update the DOM from within a loop. It will cause excessive reflows and repaints. And, never, never, never use `eval()`. (I know you're just showing what the OP used, but `eval === evil`).

Comment: $("#lga").append(`<option value="${text}">${text}</option>`); This line of code is displaying error

Comment: eval is not approach to use. @MrIbra share some code with eval. so am extends that code.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you trying to achieve ?

```js
var Abia = ['Select item...', 'Aba North', 'Aba South', 'Arochukwu', 'Bende', 'Ikwuano', 'Isiala Ngwa North', 'Isiala Ngwa South', 'Isuikwuato', 'Obi Ngwa', 'Ohafia', 'Osisioma', 'Ugwunagbo', 'Ukwa East', 'Ukwa West', 'Umuahia North', 'muahia South', 'Umu Nneochi'];

var Adamawa = ['Select item...', 'Demsa', 'Fufure', 'Ganye', 'Gayuk', 'Gombi', 'Grie', 'Hong', 'Jada', 'Larmurde', 'Madagali', 'Maiha', 'Mayo Belwa', 'Michika', 'Mubi North', 'Mubi South', 'Numan', 'Shelleng', 'Song', 'Toungo', 'Yola North', 'Yola South'];

jQuery(window).on('load', function() {
  $("#state").change(function() {
    $("#lga").empty();
    var state = $(this).val();
    var lga = eval(state);
    lga.forEach(function(element) {
      console.log(element);
      var o = new Option(element, element);
      $("#lga").append(o);

    });
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="state" id="state">
    <option selected="selected">Select item...</option>
    <option value='Abia'>Abia</option>
    <option value='Adamawa'>Adamawa</option>
</select>
<select name="lga" id="lga">
</select>
```

Comment: You should never update the DOM from within a loop. It will cause excessive reflows and repaints. And, never, never, never use `eval()`. (I know you're just showing what the OP used, but `eval === evil`).

Comment: Yes. I know eval should not be used but as you said : I used what OP used. Could be a requirement :)